# Jquery Autocomplete to ignore numbers and spaces

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to make an autocomplete functionality in my textarea field.
I'll get a JSON and autocomplete with a suggestion from a field inside it.

The way users will type will be:

```
-number- -space- -textToAutocomplete-

1 testText
```

All the samples I saw online, doesn't work when I put this number and space before the searchedtexted and none use JSON.
I don't know a lot about jQuery, I'm kind of lost on that

Comment: Could you give a link(s) to the samples you are talking about?

Comment: <script>
        $(function() {
            var words = [
                "word1",
                "word2",
                "word3",
                "word4"
            ];
            $("#words" ).autocomplete({
                source: words
            });
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to break your text from the element down into two strings, please see the link below:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Using this you will be able to search on the first or second part of the string accordingly